# how to show list of HttpError in response

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, json.net, odata, http-error

I have used below code to show the error message

```cs
var errorMessagError = new HttpError("Type Code does not exist") { { "Code", "CT-1" } };
return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, errorMessagError));
```

and output in postman is like below.

```js
{
  "error": {
    "code": "CT-1",
    "message": "Type Code does not exist"
  }
}
```

but I need to show the multiple error message at a time like below.

```js
{
  "error": {
    "code": "CT-1",
    "message": "User is not Authenticated."
  },
  "error": {
    "code": "CT-2",
    "message": "User is not Authorized."
  },
  "error": {
    "code": "CT-3",
    "message": "User is not Valid."
  }
}
```

Do we have any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have used ODataError for showing multiple child error message like below

`

```
   public HttpResponseMessage ShowErrors(List<TargetErrorCollection> childErrorColletion )
    {
       ODataError errors = new ODataError();
        errors.ErrorCode = "CT-01";
        errors.Message = "Parent details";
        errors.Details = new Collection<ODataErrorDetail>();
        ODataErrorDetail childErr= new ODataErrorDetail();
        foreach (var err in childErrorColletion)
        {
            childErr.ErrorCode = err.MessageCode;
            childErr.Target = err.Target;
            childErr.Message = err.Message;

            errors.Details.Add(childErr);
        }   
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, errors);
    }
```

`
output looks like

`{
  "error": {
    "code": "CT-01",
    "message": "Data cannot be inserted",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "CT-02",
        "target": "Code",
        "message": "Invalid value entered"
      },
      {
        "code": "CT-03",
        "target": "DataType",
        "message": "Invalid value entered"
      }
    ]
  }
}`